# SQL Server Index Scripting

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Is it possible to create a script to loop over all tables in a database generating a set of index drop scripts and create scripts separately?

What I have to do is drop all indexes on a set of databases to run a heavy data load process but then I want to re-enable all the indexes. I don't want to have to go through each table and script an index drop and then index create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Someone's already done it so no need to write a script again... :-)

[Drop All Indexes and Stats in one Script](http://jmkehayias.blogspot.com/2008/12/drop-all-indexes-and-stats-in-one.html)

Edit. Oops. To create...

*Before* you drop them... In SSMS, right-click, generate scripts, etc

Comment: So how's he going to re-create them :)

Comment: I ended up using this script to do the drops then I found an internal tool someone created to script out all the indexes thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/19/sql-server-enable-and-disable-index-non-clustered-indexes-using-t-sql/). You don't really need to drop the indexes, just disable them while your load is occurring. This script will allow you to disable the indexes for your load, then re-enable when done, and the beauty is it does it all in one shot for the whole database with a single command.

Comment: The problem with disabling the index is you can't access the table anymore, if its clustered I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with SMO, take a look at [SMO Script Index and FK's on a database](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/smo-script-index-and-fk-s-on-a-database)